Running parallel threads on Pyspark dataframe
I have to write same data to two separate data stores. I am using PySpark foreachPartition to process data parallel, and using threads to write the data to two data stores in parallel.
df.foreachPartition(
  self.manager.partition_funtion(arg1,arg2,..)
)

in Manager class
def partition_funtion(self,arg1, arg2, ...):
    
    def process_rows(rows):
        executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
        storage1 = executor.submit(upload_data, client1, rows)
        storage2 = executor.submit(upload_data, client2, rows)
        
        storage1.result()
        storage1.result()


    return process_rows


def upload_data(client, data):
    client.upload(data) 

Above approach with concurrent module results in error
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 806, in foreachPartition
    self.mapPartitions(func).count()  # Force evaluation
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 13, 10.0.36.127, executor 7): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

If I use Thread library it runs infinitely, I also used Process lib as well.
Do should be the right way to implement this?
Do should be the right way to implement this?

For a start, you're using multiprocessing, not multithreading as your question title suggests. These are two different beasts and you  can't simply mix between them. This also seems to be the problem, i.e. that your code tries to pickle (required to copy something from one process to the other)  a thread.lock instance, which can not be pickled.

Generally, it would help you and your question if you extracted a [mcve] from your code. The code snippets you show are far from enough. Perhaps also take the [tour] and read [ask].

What are the data stores for writing to?
